# solve logarithmic inequation using lagrange mean value theorem

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have this inequality: for $ x >0, x \neq 1 : \log(x) < x-1$.
If i understand it right, i should take an interval, like $(0,x)$ and prove it using the formula $ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c) $. But since $ \frac{\log(x)-\log(0)}{x-0}$ does not exist I don't know how to do it. Maybe I am doing it wrong, but how should i do it?

Comment: Try applying MVT over  an interval with endpoints 1 (not 0) and $x$.

Comment: Can i apply it for interval $(1,x)$ even though $ x \neq 1 $?

Comment: Yes, MVT will hold there. You will need to also consider the interval $[x,1]$ (when the given $x$ is less than 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \log(x)$ on $(1,x)$, $a = 1$, $b = x$.  Then invoke MVT to find $c \in (1,x)$ such that $1/c = f'(c) = (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a) = (\log x - \log 1)/(x-1)$.  Use $c > 1$ to prove the desired inequality.